# Linked list doesn't contain values greater than a certain number

Tags: java, list, linked-list

How can I create a method that would check whether or not a linked list contains any number larger than a parameter?

Let's say we have the linked list

`[ 8 7 1 3 ]`. This would return `true` and

`[ 10 12 3 2]` would return `false`.

Would this work?

```
public boolean f(int k) {
    for (int=0; int<linkedList.size(); i++) {
        if (linkedList.get(i)>k)
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Also, I need to mention, this method would not change the list in any way and it should still work if the list contains null elements.

Thanks!

Comment: You have syntax errors, did you mean for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++)?

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8

```
public boolean f(int k) {
   return !linkedList.stream().anyMatch(i-> i> k );
}
```

*clarification*: I assume that you want to return false from the method in the case that even a single element is higher then the given `k`. Hence I use anyMatch since we only need to look for one element that is higher. There is no need to loop over the whole list.

Comment: you need to return

Comment: indeed, that might help ;) and negate since want true when it's not there

Comment: I think it's a good answer, but it won't solve his future errors as he have some wrong logic in the program, I think it would be great if you also add why his code won't work the way he wants

Comment: Why not `allMatch`?

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work how you have it currently. You need to loop through the whole list before returning. The only time you should return prematurely is if you find a reason to `return false` in this context. So move your `return true` outside of your loop and then you'd be fine.

Also, try to give meaning to your method and class definitions. Saying `obj.f(12)` doesn't really say much, whereas `obj.noElementGreaterThan(12)` says a lot more.

for example:

```
public boolean noElementGreaterThan( int k ) {
   for( int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++ )
   {
      if( linkedList.get(i) > k )
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

The reason this works is because it will loop through the entire list of objects, comparing each to the value passed in (`k`). If the value is greater than `k`, then it will `return false`, meaning in this case that it does have an element greater than `k`.

Answer (score 0):

using streams you could do like this:

```
public boolean f(int k) {
    List<Integer> filtered = linkedList.stream().filter(i -> i >  k).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return !filtered.isEmpty();
}
```